# reshape error of fully connected deep neural network input in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

i'm implementing a fully connected deep neural network. to feed the network it's needed to reshape my data but i face with this error. is this any suggestion to solve it?

```
import time
start=time.time()
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
from scipy.io import loadmat

Tar_train = (x['t_train']) 
Tar_val = (x['t_val'])
Tar_test = (x['t_test'])

Signal_train = x['data_train']
Signal_val = x['data_val']
Signal_test = x['data_test']

Signal_train = np.reshape(Signal_train,(240*64)) 
Signal_val = np.reshape(Signal_val,(240*64))
Signal_test = np.reshape(Signal_test,(240*64))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(20 , activation='relu' , input_shape=(240*64,) ))
model.add(Dense(200, activation='relu'))
```

size of signal_train is (1274, 240, 64)
 size of signal_validation is (510, 240 , 64)
 size of signal_test is (764, 240, 64)

the error is:
       ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 19568640 into shape (15360,)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the error happens in the first `np.reshape`, use

```py
Signal_train = np.reshape(Signal_train, (-1, 240*64)) 
Signal_val = np.reshape(Signal_val, (-1, 240*64))
Signal_test = np.reshape(Signal_test, (-1, 240*64))
```

This is because the first dimension (1274, for `Signal_train`) is preserved when you flatten the rest of the two dimensions. When you, for example, flatten 1274 images of 240 by 64 into 1274 vectors of dimension 240*64, there are still 1274 images in total.

`-1` for the dimension size means to let numpy use whatever dimension size that fits the original size. In this case the first `-1` is implicitly `1274`, etc.

Comment: thank you. i did what you said but i faced with this error:      ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_27 to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1274,)